# Most efficient ordering of indices in vector of vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

This is primarily a C++ conceptual question. If I have a certain matrix (stored as a vector of vectors) which I have to access, whose sizes in each dimension are very different. I have a lot of steps where I loop through the larger dimension and perform operations across the smaller dimension. I'm wondering from the view point of efficiency with respect to access time and operations on this matrix, which of the following two examples would be more efficient:

Organization 1:

```
A=vector<vector<float>>(1000,vector<float>(10,0.0)); 
sumAcrossSmallerDimension=vector<float>(1000,0.0);

for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        sumAcrossSmallerDimension[i]+=A[i][j];
```

Organization 2:

```
A=vector<vector<float>>(10,vector<float>(1000,0.0)); 
sumAcrossSmallerDimension=vector<float>(1000,0.0);
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        sumAcrossSmallerDimension[i]+=A[j][i];
```

In the second example it seems like each set A entries would get loaded faster, but in order to sum across the j Dimension, you'd be jumping in memory 10 times per i iteration to find the corresponding j entry.

In the first example, it seems like loading A would be slower but then all entries in the lower dimension are readily available to sum.

Curious about this, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think a linear address space rather than a vector of vectors will give you the best cache locality:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

struct vv
{
  vv(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns, double init)
    : _rows(rows), _columns(columns), _size(_rows * _columns)
    , _pdata(std::make_unique<double[]>(_size))
    {
      std::fill(_pdata.get(), _pdata.get() + _size, init);
    }

  const double* operator[](std::size_t i) const {
    return std::addressof(_pdata.get()[i * _columns]);
  }

  double rowSum(std::size_t i) const {
    auto p = (*this)[i];
    return std::accumulate(p, p + _columns, 0.0, std::plus<>());
  }

  std::size_t _rows, _columns, _size;
  std::unique_ptr<double[]> _pdata;
};

int main()
{
  vv v(1000, 10, 10.0);

  auto sumAcrossSmallerDimension = std::vector<double>(1000,0.0);
  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
  {
    sumAcrossSmallerDimension[i] += v.rowSum(i);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! If my understanding it correctly, you're "rolling out" the 2D vector of vectors into a linear vector...I can go ahead and try that. 

Just for my knowledge in general, if one were to use a 2D array and I was restricted to looping the way I have shown above (i=0 : 1000, then j=0:10)...which of the two above might be faster?

Comment: @SiddharthKrishnamoorthy in this case, probably the one that gives you linear runs across the smaller dimension - because of the way that memory is fetched into the cache.

Comment: if I may ask you one more question (sorry if it's a dumb question), is cache locality very important if you're not looping through a vector and directly accessing one member? so something like 
v[5]=2; 
Would cache locality still be important in this case?

Comment: Cache locality can't help with random access. But it's incredibly important for sequential  access.